# How can I wait for transaction to confirm using tonweb?

Tags: ton

I'm writing a simple DApp on *TON blockchain* and using `tonweb` to interact with it.

I need to send some transaction and after it confirms on chain, perform some other things in JS.
Example:

```
await ton.send('ton_sendTransaction', [{
        to: 'some address',
        value: '1000'
    }]
)

// wait for tx to confirm on chain

console.log('Done!')
```

But I don't understand how can I do that using tonweb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach would be saving last user's transaction and run a loop until user's address will have new transacations.

You can do it like that with tonweb:

```
// Get user's wallet address from TON wallet browser extension
const address = (await ton.send('ton_requestAccounts'))[0]

// Get user's last transaction hash using tonweb
const lastTx = (await tonweb.getTransactions(address, 1))[0]
const lastTxHash = lastTx.transaction_id.hash

// Send your transaction
await ton.send('ton_sendTransaction', [{
        to: 'some address',
        value: '1000'
    }]
)

// Run a loop until user's last tx hash changes
var txHash = lastTxHash
while (txHash == lastTxHash) {
    await sleep(1500) // some delay between API calls
    let tx = (await tonweb.getTransactions(address, 1))[0]
    txHash = tx.transaction_id.hash
}

console.log('Done!')
```